# How to get data to html file by $http.get() from .json file

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angular, http

I'm trying to display a list `<li>` with `ng-repeat` by extracting data from `data/states.json` file by using `$http.get()` method. Can any one please help me to slove this.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in state">{{ x }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
       var app = angular.module("app",[]);
       app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
           $http.get("data/states.json").then(function(response) {
               $scope.state = response.data;
           });
       });
    </script>
```

.json file

```
[ "Alabama (AL)",
"Alaska (AK)",
"Arizona (AZ)",
"Arkansas (AR)" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the data from the response as follows,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("data.json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.state = response;})
  .error(function (response) {alert("Error")})
});
```

**[`PLUNKER DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/R8fgBIWP65ApPCBEqeHK?p=preview)**

Comment: check the demo above

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="find" style="text-align:center;">
 <h3 class="find">Find A Park By State</h3>
 <select style="width: 200px; height: 20px; ">
  <option ng-repeat=" x in state"> {{ x }} </option>
 </select> 
</div>

Comment: var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $response){
 $http.get("data/states.json")
 .success(function(response) {
  $scope.state = response ; 
 })
});